# Download HTML of a webpage that is changed by JavaScript

Tags: java, javascript, html

The program I am writing is in Java.

I am writing a little program that will download the html of webpages and save them.  It works easily for basic pages that don't use JavaScript.  But how can I download the page if I want it after a script has updated it?  The page I am dealing with is actually updated by Ajax which might be one step harder.

I understand that this is probably a difficult problem that involves setting up a JavaScript run time environment of some kind.  I am prepared for a solution of any level of difficulty, I just don't know exactly how to approach it or where to get started.

Comment: How will you know that the script(s) are finished? What if there are continuous animations or other DOM changes?

Comment: If you can run a JavaScript snippet from Java, you can get the contents of the page with `document.body.innerHTML` (and `document.head.innerHTML`). But I too have the same question @LeeTaylor has.

Comment: I am familiar with the site and in this particular case that should not be a problem.  Although, I see how it could be hard to make a general tool for this.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that alone with Java only. As the page that you want to download is rendered with javascript, then you must be able to execute the javascript to get the whole rendered page.

Because of this situation, you need to use a headless browser which is a web browser that can access to web pages but can’t show the output within a GUI, aims to provide the content of web pages as fully rendered to serve to the programs or scripts.

You can start with the most famous ones which are [Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/), [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) and [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/)

Comment: I've never heard of PhantomJS before, I just played with it for a bit and it is AWESOME! Thanks for making me aware of it.

Comment: @4th_dimention you could do this in Java by making a command line call to a simple PhantomJS script which takes a webpage as an argument and renders it.